# Why does Dekomori's shirt say "Purgatory" in Chuunibyou demo Koi ga Shitai?

Tags: love-chunibyo-and-other-delusions

In episode 6 of Chuunibyou demo Koi ga Shitai!, Rikka gives the members a "uniform" which is a black shirt with 2 kanji on the front. Hers reads "Evil Eye" (jagan), Yuuta's reads "Dark Flame" (yami honoo), Kumin's reads "Black Dream" (kuro yume), and **Dekomori's reads "Purgatory" (rengoku)**.

I think they never mention what Kumin's or Dekomori's say, so I had to translate them myself, and Kumin's made sense, but I don't understand Dekomori's. Is there any other reference to her as "purgatory" or anything?

Comment: Perhaps related: [Is Dekomori meant to say “desu” or “death”?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/29935)

Comment: As I recall, Dekomori didn't have a chuuni alias/codename (a la Dark Flame Master or Morisummer/Forest Summer/however you want to localize it), and was largely referred to by her supposed weapon, the "Mjolnir Hammer", during chuuni activities. This is just a guess, but her shirt might have been "Purgatory" since she tends to base most, if not all, of her chuuni persona around that of Rikka, and thus would want kanji for something "darker" to match her "master".